# Can a man offer Pind-daan to his maternal ancestors?

Tags: rituals, death, ancestry

Can a man offer Pind-daan to his maternal ancestors i.e. - Nana, Nani etc or only to Paternal ancestors?

Comment: A man has to mandatorily offer Pind to even maternal side that is Nana nani even to par nana and par nani, as those too count in pitras.